# Flutter: Make Text as big as possible by removing all its padding

Tags: flutter, dart

**Code:**

```
Container(
  color: Colors.blue,
  child: Text("8", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 400),),
)
```

---

**Output:**

[image]

---

**Problem:**

How can I remove vertical padding in the `Text`, I want it to be as tall and as wide as possible.

---

**Note:**

I'm not looking for workarounds like using `Transform` `Matrix4.diagonal3Values` and making `y` to be `1.x`. The solution should be universal.

Comment: I think it depends the font you use. Character in Font have space around it.

Answer (score 2):

fonts themselves have padding.

you can use something like [FontForge](http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/downloads/) to edit a font and create a custom font without padding and use that instead.

[image]

also try setting `TextStyle.inherit = false` if there is still some padding in bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using padding, something like given below.

```
body: Container(
    color: Colors.blue,
    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
    child:    Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Text("8", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 400,), ),
      ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: Thanks but your solution adds more padding to it.